# Matching regular expression with Date/Numbers

Tags: php, regex

I need some help creating regular expressions to pick information out of a file. I am using php preg_match to do it and am trying to get information that looks like the following:

ex.

```
19-Aug-2013 //The date will always be in the format.
```

and a number like this

```
303.00
```

The file I am trying to get this information from is the body of a mime type email.

I only need these two types of specific information.

Comment: Any code you can show us? Please include sample inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: please provide a sample of your file so we know what the format is.

Comment: Sample outputs are nice, but sample input is also great.

Comment: You can get started on regexes with [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). It's a fantastic resource for all things regex.

Comment: What regex have you tried so far? Any basic regex tutorial should cover this.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a whole:

`preg_match_all('/(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}|\d+\.\d{1,2})/', $file, $matches);`

`\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}`: Get the date

`\d+\.\d{1,2}`: Get the float

By using `preg_match_all` you return all found matches in all the haystack. `preg_match` only matches the first occurance.

Answer (score 1):

For the date you can use:

```
[0-9]{2}-[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

For the number:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}
```

With no specific input is hard to come up with a better regex at the moment...